# How can I use Python Mechanize to fill out a web form that requires Javascript?

Tags: python, mechanize

I was trying to fill a form using mechanize. But the problem is the webpage needs javascript. So whenever I try to make an access to the page, the page redirects to an error page saying javascript needed. Is there a way to enable javascript when using mechanize browser?

Here is the code

```
import mechanize
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("https://192.168.10.3/connect/PortalMain")
for f in br.forms():
    print f
```

Also when I tried to extract the  webpage using BeautifulSoup that '*works fine on my browser*' I got the same problem. It redirects to a new page. 
(I tried disabling javascript on my browser and got the page which beautiful soup was showing me.)

Here is the code of BeautifulSoup if it helps

```
import ssl
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
page = urllib2.urlopen("https://192.168.10.3/connect/PortalMain")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
print soup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just go ahead and use Selenium instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

usernameStr = 'putYourUsernameHere'
passwordStr = 'putYourPasswordHere'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://192.168.10.3/connect/PortalMain')

# fill in username and hit the next button (replace selectors!)
username = browser.find_element_by_id('Username')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)
password = browser.find_element_by_id('Password')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
loginButton = browser.find_element_by_id('login')
loginButton.click()
```

This will use the Chrome web driver to open your browser and login, you can switch it to use any other driver Selenium supports e.g. Firefox.

Source: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/automate-create-login-bot-python-selenium/

Remember you might need to make adjustments if the site is using a self-signed certificate.

Comment: How do I add support for untrusted/self-signed certificate

Comment: It is giving me an error at the browser line

  `File "demo.py", line 9, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

Comment: You need to install the chromedriver which is detailed in the source link above that I sent you. There is even a link to the instructions for solving this inside the error message.

Comment: Also don't use Python 2.7 for new projects, you should be using Python 3.6 whenever starting a new project unless there is a specific reason that you can't.

Comment: No problem, if this answer is correct I'd be grateful if you could mark it as the accepted answer.